# Как считать значение пикселя в отдельном окне

Tags: python, pywin32

мне нужно считать значение определенного пикселя из окна приложения, нашел только как это сделать для всего экрана.

```
import win32gui

def pixel_color_at(x, y):
    hdc = win32gui.GetWindowDC(win32gui.GetDesktopWindow())
    c = int(win32gui.GetPixel(hdc, x, y))
    return (c & 0xff), ((c >> 8) & 0xff), ((c >> 16) & 0xff)# (r, g, b)
```

Но мне хотелось бы, чтобы приложение работало на фоне, желательно было свернуто (ну или хотя бы на втором плане, чтобы не мешалось), возможно ли это реализовать технически?